# Book Recommendations on Perturbation Theory

Tags: asymptotics, book-recommendation, perturbation-theory

I am interested in studying Quantum Electrodynamics and figure I should begin by learning Perturbation theory and Asymptotic expansions.  If anyone could recommend some books, that would be very appreciated.

Comment: There is a book by Tosio Kato on perturbation theory which is quite esteemed.  There's always Reed and Simon on mathematical physics.  There's Robin Ticciati's *Quantum Field Theory for Mathematicians*.  All that said, if you are mathematically trained and trying to read a book on QED like say Tannoudji Dupont Grinberg, you will probably find yourself asking questions about the derivations and equations which are none too easy to answer.  More than any math, you need to understand well the physicists' way of expounding nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, using generally only 19th century math.

Comment: bender orszag might be useful

Comment: great, thanks @ForgotALot !

Comment: and @tired (stackexchange apparently doesn't let you @ more than one person per comment lol)

Comment: @ForgotALot taking your comment into consideration (about questioning derivations and equations), would you recommend to wait to learn QED (or other similarly complex topics in physics) until a course, or try to trek through a book and use stackexchange for help?

Comment: I don't know.  I just believe that the reasoning styles of mathematicians and physicists differ, they manipulate equations differently, and to do QED or even nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, you need to accept and assimilate the physicists' way.